# Lock picking, lockpicking, or lock-picking: Which is correct to use?

Tags: orthography

I am trying to identify which usage is correct or most common in American English: lock picking, lockpicking, or lock-picking.

I found no results in Merriam-Webster online, and data from [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lockpicking%2Clock%20picking&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clockpicking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clock%20picking%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clockpicking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clock%20picking%3B%2Cc0) and [Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) was inconclusive. There is an international association, [TOOOL](https://toool.us/), that treats the phrase as a single word, and the Wikipedia article on this subject actually formats the phrase in two different ways.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “correct”.

Comment: @tchrist - Agreed. All three forms are correct, though the last one is not much in use. I see more of *"lock picking"*.

Comment: I think that one can reasonably conclude from the data afforded by [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lock+picking%2Clockpicking&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clock%20picking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clockpicking%3B%2Cc0) that (a) the open form is more commonly used than the closed (though the tool doesn't differentiate premodifier, pure noun, and predicative usages), though (b) favoured choice has changed over time, and (c) both open and closed forms are used....

Comment: Assessing popularity of the hyphenated form is more difficult; [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lock+picking%2Clockpicking%2Clock-picking&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clock%20picking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clockpicking%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clock%20-%20picking%3B%2Cc0) seemed to indicate it was easily the most popular form, but a quick look on a Google search seems to give the lie to this; I suspect a processing glitch throws up the spurious result.